# How to handle events (buttonclicks etc.) with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm am still a bit confused what to put in a fragment and what to put in an activity.

In general I have a app with a navigation drawer with an items in it like notes(where an almost blank page is created where I can put notes for a day) and bucketlist(this just opens a list where I can add an delete items)

What would be an activity and what would be a fragment. At the moment every button in my NavDrawer opens an acitivty with it's on fragment and implements an interface defined in the fragment for handling all button clicks.

So you can actually see the swap to a new activity, when clicking and not just changing the fragment.

My question is how should I handle this.

1. Like it is now. Every item in NavDrawer is linked to an activity which implements the interface from the fragment to handle the button clicks etc.
2. The main activity implements all the different interfaces(events) from the fragments and just switches fragments.
   This should be smoother for the user, but I feel like the man activity will just have so many function for all different fragments.
3. The events(e.g. button clicks) are handled in the fragment itself and the main activity just switches fragments. This should be smooth for the user and doesn't create such a big main activity. This just bothers me a bit, as I thought fragments should just define the layout and not handle actions. (The standard example with navdrawer from android studio also forwards the clicks from the fragments to its activity)

At the moment the only moment, where I swap fragments without activity is if someone will go to detaile pages. Like clicking on a bucketlist item to get more details.

Perhaps someone could explain what to use or if there are different times when to use these methods.

Short version of the question with example:

WhatsApp(cant link as I'm a new user):

What would be the got to way to implement the tabs Calls, Chats, Contacts

That's what I got with google search:

This is what I found suggesting method 3:
http://weimenglee.blogspot.de/2013/08/android-tip-handling-events-in-fragment.html

This is from google developers. They create an extra class to handle the events:
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Fragments | Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity.

So it's entirely appropriate for the fragments to handle button clicks, as in your Option 3 above.

Here is the rule I use:  If the fragment can handle the entire behavior, then it should.  If the fragment can't handle the entire behavior, then call a method on the activity to notify it that the event happened, and have the activity "forward" the behavior by calling methods on its fragments.

I recently coded a feature with fragments handled by a `ViewPager` inside another fragment.  For me it helped to group of the actions to be performed into responsibilities and asking "which fragment/activity should be responsible for ...?"